# CSS expand width from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to build an effect like jQuery's accordion. I have 10 items that fill the screen; when the mouse hovers over an item, it expands in width. How I can make it expand from right to left for the last 5 items?

My HTML :

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div style="width: 165.25px; background: rgb(228, 228, 230);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 165.25px; background: rgb(35, 123, 192);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 165.25px; background: rgb(20, 4, 4);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 165.25px; background: rgb(182, 159, 36);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 165.25px; background: rgb(162, 169, 180);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 161px; background: rgb(37, 29, 4);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 161px; background: red;" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 161px; background: rgb(88, 45, 45);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 161px; background: rgb(202, 41, 176);" class="item"></div>
    <div style="width: 161px; background: rgb(24, 207, 185);" class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.wrap{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.item').each(function(e){
    $(this).css('width', ($(this).parent().width()/10));
});

$('.item').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    $(this).stop().animate({width: "50%"}, {duration: 500});
}).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    $(this).stop().animate({width: ($(this).parent().width()/10)}, {duration: 500});
});
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/thanhlk/fydhbsbe/3/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another wrapper div inside  with a big width which makes sure that your floating elements don't wrap to the next line. Then, scroll the outer wrapping div to the correct position when the hovered element is #5 or higher:

```
$('.item').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    //Animate width
    $(this).stop().animate({width: $(this).parent().parent().width()/2}, {duration: 500});
    if($(this).index() >= 5){
        //Animate scrollLeft
        var marginLeft = $(this).parent().parent().width() / 10 * 4;
        $(this).parent().parent().stop().animate({scrollLeft: marginLeft + 'px'}, {duration: 500});
    }
}).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    //Animate width
    $(this).stop().animate({width: ($(this).parent().parent().width()/10)}, {duration: 500});
    //Animate scrollLeft
    $(this).parent().parent().stop().animate({scrollLeft: 0}, {duration: 500});
});
```

You can see it working here: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fydhbsbe/21/)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to reduce width of other items during increasing width of hovered element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fydhbsbe/22/).

```
var items = $('.item');
var itemsCount = items.length;
var fullWidth = $('.item:first').parent().width();

items.each(function()
{
    $(this).css('width', fullWidth / itemsCount);
});

items.on('mouseenter', function()
{
    items.not(this).stop().animate({ width: fullWidth / itemsCount / 2 }, 500);
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: "50%" }, 500 );
});

items.on('mouseleave', function()
{
    items.stop().animate({ width: fullWidth / itemsCount }, 500);
});
```

There is one weird thing: due to `fullWidth / itemsCount / 2` instead of correct `fullWidth / (itemsCount - 1) / 2` there is empty place on right border of accordion, but with `fullWidth / (itemsCount - 1) / 2` last element sometimes disappeares from screen.